# Issues with retrieving objects from a HashMap of HashMaps

Tags: java, recursion, hashmap

I am writing code that iterates recursively through an XML file and populates a HashMap of HashMaps. I have been able to populate the hashmap and it looks OK. However, when I run this command

```
 System.out.println(map.containsKey("Mary"));
```

Its always false. Really not sure why it always returns false. I have also posted my recursive code and contents of the hashmap after

```
map.toString() 
map is { Mary
    ={24
        ={established
            ={western
                ={Profile=m}}, torn-down
            ={western
                ={Profile=b}, eastern
                ={Profile=m}}}, 44
        ={established
            ={western
                ={Profile=g}, eastern
                ={Profile=s}}, torn-down
            ={western
                ={Profile=j}, western
                ={Profile=f}}}}, Martha
    ={24
        ={established
            ={western
                ={Profile=a}}, torn-down
            ={western
                ={Profile=b}, eastern
                ={Profile=n}}}, 44
        ={established
            ={western
                ={Profile=s}, eastern
                ={Profile=j}}, torn-down
            ={western
                ={Profile=k}, eastern
                ={Profile=g}}}}}
```

Recursive code is:

```
NodeList l = doc.getElementsByTagName("Branches");
        Node n = l.item(0);
        map = new HashMap();
        recurse(n, map);

private void recurse(Node n, HashMap map){
if (n.hasChildNodes()){
    NodeList nl = n.getChildNodes();

    for(int i= 0; i< nl.getLength(); i++){
        Node node = nl.item(i);

        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
            if (!node.getNodeName().equals("Profile") ){

                map.put(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(), new HashMap());

                recurse(node, (HashMap)map.get(node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()));
            }
            else {

                map.put("Profile", node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }


            }
        }       
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid using raw types when possible, and prefer using the [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) - it will make your code both more readable and both type safe. If you are looking for unlimited nesting - I'd use the composite design pattern to achieve it, but it is just a suggestion :)

Comment: is there a space before "Mary" ? what does map.containsKey(" Mary") give you?

Comment: @kent thanks but map.containsKey(" Mary") still returns false. I also tried putting a space after Mary but still false.

Comment: @amit I'm not familiar with the composite design pattern but I'll read up on it. Thanks.

Comment: @user1192724: can you please add the following line and tell us what it prints? `System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next().getClass());`? I am trying to check if the first key is a `String` object. [I am assuming Mary is the only key in the test data, if it is not, we might need to iterate and print all types for all elements]

Comment: @amit It prints out class java.lang.String

Comment: @user1192724: And can you also add `String s = (String)map.keySet().iterator().next();  System.out.println("val=" + s + " length=" + s.length());`? I am now trying to check what is exactly the `String` object, and see if there are invisible characters - if there are, it will be reflected in `length=...`

Comment: @amit You're right. There are invisible characters. its prints out val=Mary length=7. Where could these extra chars have been introduced and it is possible to get rid of them? Also I have 2 keys; 'Mary' and 'Martha', I looped through and they are both java.lang.String

Comment: @amit I did a str.replaceAll("\\s", ""); and that has trimmed all the invisible chars.

Comment: @Amit it works! Thanks! So after getting data from the XML file and before populating the HashMap, I remove all the whitespace characters and now it works fine. Thanks a lot! Can you rewrite your comment as an answer so I can give it an upvote?

Comment: @user1192724: You are most welcome. I wrapped this discussion as an answer. I am glad I could help you - and more important, to show you how you should approach this in the future, and how to look for the reason of the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by the OP- and since the Discussion in comments solved his issue - I am wrapping it as answer - for future readers:

First, you should check if your keys are indeed `String` objects. You can do it by adding the line:

```
System.out.println(map.keySet().iterator().next().getClass());
```

Next, after we have established your keys are indeed `String`s, we want to check if you have invisible characters or not needed white spaces, we will do it by adding the following lines:

```
String s = (String)map.keySet().iterator().next(); 
System.out.println("val=" + s + " length=" + s.length());
```

If there is indeed invisible characters - we will know it since the length will not match.

If it is indeed the reason [and it is, as the OP said], you will have to process your strings when reading the XML to exclude this characters.

Also, as a side note - I'd recommend avoiding using raw types, and will suggest you to use [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) whenever it is possible. It will give you both more readable code, and both [type safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety)! 
If you want unlimited nesting, then I would have used the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to achieve it.